# the heading title

Tags: grammar

I have a document file listing 3 projects.

I'm not sure the heading title should be "PROJECT" or "PROJECTS", hope someone can help on this.

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE, but naming and labeling are not really about the use of the English language. You can name anything any way you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Projects

because you have multiple projects.

Comment: Yes, even if @Dinh Xuan Nhat had only a single project in the list at a given time, it would still be appropriate to maintain a list called "Projects".